# Attribute not updating on update_attribute even after reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm doing the rails tutorial on :

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset

I have this piece of code that is supossed to create a reset_token and save its hash and the time it was created to the database.

```
def create_reset_digest
    self.reset_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:reset_digest,  User.digest(reset_token))
    value = update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)
    print value
end
```

Starting debug before update_attribute on reset_sent_at:

```
self.reset_sent_at == 2000-01-01 12:36:53 UTC
```

After it:

```
self.reset_sent_at == Thu, 22 Oct 2015 12:52:47 UTC +00:00
```

But doing self.reload makes:

```
self.reset_sent_at == 2000-01-01 12:36:53 UTC
```

So maybe update_attribute is not saving on the db?

But print value returns True, indicating a successful save.

I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: Are you sure you are reloading the record. For debugging purposes, try adding `self.reload` after `update_attribute(:reset_sent_at, Time.zone.now)` and then `puts self.reset_sent_at`. Are your tests failing?

Comment: There is one test failing, which is the test for successful reset, it says the link has expired.

Inserting the self.reload and puts still prints 2000-01-01 12:36:53 UTC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what happened, on the schema I had t.time for "reset_sent_at"
instead of t.datetime. Weird that the update_attribute returned true.